# What's the QtNetwork equivalent of shutdown(..., SHUT_WR)

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp

I need to close the writing side (send FIN) of a TCP socket using QtNetwork.

With BSD sockets i'd call shutdown(..., SHUT_WR).

How do i do that with the QtNetwork API?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

```
void QIODevice::setOpenMode(QIODevice::ReadOnly)
```

should help:

```
void QIODevice::setOpenMode(OpenMode openMode) [protected]
Sets the OpenMode of the device to openMode. Call this function to set the open mode if the flags change after the device has been opened.
```

Comment: Bleh no wonder i didn't see it, considering the not-really-intuitive name and the fact that it's on QIODevice. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be wrong, nothing seems to happen after the call and FIN isn't sent to the other side. Reading the source it looks like setOpenMode just changes some flags.

Comment: It makes the socket read-only, but does not send FIN i think. Shouldn't SHUT_WR do the same, given from the docs it disables further writing to the socket.

Comment: Ok, i found an appendix: ``Implementation Notes: PF_INET::SOCK_STREAM IPPROTO_TCP::Return 0.  Send queued data, wait for ACK, then send FIN.``, but this seems really BSD-socket specific, i'll take a look into later

Comment: It's not BSD specific, most socket APIs have something like that (shutdown(...,SD_SEND) in winsock, socket.shutdownOutput in java, etc.) and it's used in some protocols. For example in HTTP you can do a half-close to signal to the server when you are done sending a request (in cases when you can't use content-length for some reason)